# Using Selenium to select text

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Want to select the text "This is for testing selector" from below HTML code.

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
    <a title=" Home" href="http://www.google.com/"> Home</a> 
    <span class="arrow">»</span>
    <a title="abc" href="http://www.google.com/">test1</a> 
    <span class="arrow">»</span><a title="xyz" href="http://www.google.com/">test2</a> 
    <span class="arrow">»</span> 
    This is for testing selector
    </div>
```

Comment: did you try with `.getText();`

Comment: @ Emna : it will not work

Comment: sorry i didn't concentrate a lot, i put an answer check it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there an easy way out for this or not. It turned out to be more difficult than I thought. Below mentioned code is tested locally and giving correct output for me ;)

```
String MyString= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='breadcrumb']")).getText();
    //get all child nodes of div parent class
    List<WebElement> ele= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='breadcrumb']/child::*"));
        for(WebElement i:ele) {
        //substracing a text of child node from parent node text
        MyString= MyString.substring(i.getText().length(), MyString.length());
        //removing white spaces
        MyString=MyString.trim();
            }

    System.out.println(MyString);
```

Let me know if it works for you or not!

Answer (score 0):

[image]Try with this example :

```
    driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
    WebElement text = 
    findElement(By.className("breadcrumb")).find("span").get(1);

    Actions select = new Actions(driver);
    select.doubleClick(text).build().perform();
```

I suggest also that you copy the xpath for the text you need and put it here to have the exact xpath 
[image]

Comment: i don't know the path of the text you want to select, it's just an example to show you the select action that has to be done!

Comment: text won't be having any x-path

Comment: put the location of your element instead of (By.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'google')]")) it's just an example because i don't know exactly the id of your element

Comment: how can i print the text "This is for testing selector" from the code you provided

Comment: You have to search for it's locators

Comment: My question is crytal clear and simple ..... How can i select and get the text "This is for testing selector" printed into console.  Hope its clear now

Comment: Emna do me a favour, just save the below code provided with .html extension and try to select the text i am talking about.  <html>
<body>
<div class="breadcrumb">
    <a title=" Home" href="http://www.google.com/"> Home</a> 
    <span class="arrow">»</span>
    <a title="abc" href="http://www.google.com/">test1</a> 
    <span class="arrow">»</span><a title="xyz" href="http://www.google.com/">test2</a> 
    <span class="arrow">»</span> 
    This is for testing selector
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: i am not sure why are u doing this "driver.get("http://www.google.com/");"  simply add the HTML code in notepad and save the file with .html and try to do the task i mentiond

Comment: it's just an example i'm trying to explain you the action of select ! because you didn't put your code

Comment: i'm always learning and major project i'm working in protractor and appium so that my code looks a bit like protractor

Answer (score 0):

<del>You cannot select text inside an element using xpath.
Xpath can only help you select XML elements, or in this case, HTML elements.</del> 
Typically, text should be encased in a span tag, however, in your case, it isn't.

<del>What you could do, however, is select the div element encasing the text.</del> Try this xpath :

```
(//div[@class='breadcrumb']/span)[3]/following-sibling::text()
```

<del>You could try Abhijeet's Answer if you just want to get the text inside. As an added check, check if the string obtained from using `getText()` on root element contains the string obtained from using `getText()` on the child elements.</del>